# Params not being saved in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, parameters

Disclaimer: I am very new to Ruby + rails. I'm not sure if this is a bug, but my `params` variable always seems to be null. I am working on a large and unfamiliar codebase so I'm not sure if it's something else interfering or my own code; any suggestions would be welcome however.

In my routes file I have `match '/proxy_request/:number/:ref' => 'proxies#show', via: :get`- I was under the impression that this would store `:number` and `:ref` variables in `params`. However when my `proxies#show` function runs (below), params is an empty hash.

In case it probably is something else interfering with `params`, is there another way to pass `:number` and `:ref` to `proxies#show`?

```
class ProxiesController < ApplicationController

  include Service

  skip_before_action :restrict_access!

  def show
    binding.pry #params is null here
    data = { date: Adapter.staging_date.get(params[:number], params[:ref])}
    render json: data, content_type: "application/javascript", callback: @_request.env["QUERY_STRING"].match(/jQuery\d*_\d*/)
  end

end
```

Comment: so you are accessing this using a route that looks like `/proxy_request/x/y` correct where `x` is :number and `y` is :ref? This is how those variables end up in params.

Comment: how do you call this route?

Comment: You're on the right way. Check your link again.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, however they are not being passed in; might be an access control issue

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: @Bustikiller Rails 5

Comment: I am not sure if it will solve your problem, but have a look at strong parameters in controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `include Service` and all seems to be ok now